# Delete Commit in git History

Tags: git, git-push

How can delete one duplicate commit in Git ? I cannot push because I get the error:

```
error : duplicate commit
```

I can't seem to be able to delete this commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $br is empty, the checkout cmd creates a branch whose name is 95196f3b7ac656803cd4ed703d6d06b15e527e40 which points to HEAD. However it's also the name of a git object, the commit 95196f3b7ac656803cd4ed703d6d06b15e527e40. When you run `git show 95196f3b7ac656803cd4ed703d6d06b15e527e40`, git does not know to show HEAD or the true 95196f3b7ac656803cd4ed703d6d06b15e527e40. So it's ambitious.

Answer (score 0):

If you figure out what that ref is to:

`git [log|branch|tag] | grep 95196f3b7ac656803cd4ed703d6d06b15e527e40`

...then you can delete or push it, as appropriate.